# Invalid subscription key at luis.ai

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I sign in to [luis.ai](https://www.luis.ai/home), it shows below error message. I have Owner role or Contributor role on my subscriptions. How to fix the error? Thanks.

> 401: Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API
>   endpoint. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription
>   and use a correct regional API endpoint for your resource.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens when you have deleted and recreated (or just deleted) the authoring resource you last used in the https://www.luis.ai/ portal. To fix this, reselect the Subscription and a valid Authoring Resource, then ***reload the page*** (it usually doesn't fix the issue if you just select the authoring resource). You may have to explicitly browse back to https://www.luis.ai/.

If this doesn't work, check to make sure that your authoring resource still exists.